# AngularJS How i can filter nested object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I filter nested object in AngularJS? I created a function to get the `proptypes`. I want to filter `type1.value = false`.

#### JSON:

```
scope.States = {
  "1": {
    "Prop": {
      "id": 1
    },
    "PropTypes": {
      "Type1": {
        "date": "2015-05-30T01:01:04",
        "value": false,
        "id": 1,
        "name": "defautPompier"
      },
      "Type2": {
        "date": "2015-05-30T01:01:04",
        "value": true,
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Delestage"
      }
    },
    "defaultsInstallations": ["defautPompier", "Delestage"]
  }
}
```

#### Controller:

```
$scope.GetDefaultByInstallation = function(title) {
    $scope.installationsStates = [];
    var res;
    $scope.result = [];
    Object.keys($scope.States).forEach(function(key) {
          var res = false;
          angular.forEach($scope.States[key].PropTypes, function(value, cle) {
                if ($scope.States[key].PropTypes[cle] == title) {
                  res = true;
                }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

For filtering data you have two different method:

1. Inside the html
2. In a function inside controllers

[By documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter)

```
{{ expression [| filter_name[:parameter_value] ... ] }}
```

In this case thanks to the "pipe" you can add a filter in your code.

E.g.
HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="friend in person.friends | startsWithA">
    {{ friend }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
app.filter('startsWithA', function () {
  return function (items) {
    var filtered = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var item = items[i];
      // ... your logic for filter items
      // E.G.
      if (/a/i.test(item.name.substring(0, 1))) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    }
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

You can also filter your data on controller (**you must add to the scope a new filtered list**) and then add inside `ng-repeat` your filtered list.